# recursive Javascript camelCase explanation

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am trying to understand how this recursion function works to convert JSON keys to camelCase. Can someone comment on it for each line and/or add explanation? Thank you!

```
function toCamel(o) {
  var newO, origKey, newKey, value;

  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o.map(function(value) {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        value = toCamel(value);
      }

      return value;
    });
  } else {
    newO = {};

    for (origKey in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
        newKey = (origKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + origKey.slice(1) || origKey).toString();
        value = o[origKey];

        if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
          value = toCamel(value);
        }

        newO[newKey] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  return newO;
}
```

Comment: No JSON was observed. You're talking about JavaScript Objects, not JSON. JSON is _always_ a plain string.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've commented the code to explain what is happening, let me know if it doesn't make sense! It is basically going through each item from what you pass to it (json) and processing each item again if it is an array or object. It's converting the key to a string and setting the first character to lowercase.

```
// create a test json array;
var json = {
"TestArr": [
    {"TestKey": 1, "ItemIDs": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"TestKey": 2, "ItemIDs": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
  ]
};

function toCamel(o) {
  var newO, origKey, newKey, value
  // if the passed parameter is an Array...
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    // iterate through each item in the array... 
    return o.map(function(value) {
        // if the current item is an object...
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        // send the current item to this function...
        // this time as an oblect
        value = toCamel(value)
      }
      // return the current item
      return value
    });
  // if the passed item is an object...
  } else {
    // create a temporary object
    newO = {}
    // for each key in the object
    for (origKey in o) {
        // check to make sure the object has a property of the current key
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
        // convert the key to a string, then make the first character in the string lowercase
        newKey = (origKey.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + origKey.slice(1) || origKey).toString()
        // set the value var equal to the current key value
        value = o[origKey]
        // if value is an array OR the value isn't null AND its constructor is an Object...
        // (ensure the value is an array or object)
        if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
            // set value to this function for more processing
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        // set the temporary object key value to the new processed value or the original value if not an array/object
        newO[newKey] = value
      }
    }
  }
  // return the finished/formatted JSON
  return newO;
}

// set a variable to the value returned from the toCamel function
var test = toCamel(json);
// write out the result in the console
console.log(test);
```